# What is a "security bod"?

Tags: terminology

This is a term I ran across in [a blog post by Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-ethics-of-running-a-data-breach-search-service/) (which was linked from [an answer on this site](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/201655/96753)):

> I heard a perfect example of this just the other day when speaking to a **security bod** in a bank.

I searched the term in DuckDuckGo and found no definitions, though I found two "Inquirer" headlines that use the same phrase:

> Linus Torvalds slams Google **security bod's** 'bullsh*t' approach to bugs

And:

> **Security bod** uncovers 15-year-old macOS zero-day flaw

I also found UK's "The Register" using the term in a headline.

What does this term mean and is there any etymology for it?  (Neither "body" nor "board of directors" fits the context.)

Comment: Seems to be [British English slang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bod#English) for "person".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed English slang and therefore this question relates more to etymology than security.

Wiktionary [describes it](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bod) as:

> (slang) **A person**.
>   George was a bit of an odd bod.
>
> 2005, Richard Templar, The Rules of Management (page 73) There were cameras covering car parks, offices, corridors and storage areas in the basement. Result. **The security bods** started watching as if their lives depended on it.

(Emphasis mine)